# Hiera-eyaml-Kms - decrypting issue when it used in puppet

Tags: puppet, hiera, amazon-kms

I'm using Kms key  in puppet to decrypt some secrets , im getting bellow error while decrypting the secrets

```
Error: Evaluation Error: Error while evaluating a Function Call, missing region; use :region option or export region name to ENV['AWS_REGION'] at /init.pp:3:18 on node
```

This is my hiera config file which i have configured kms key id and region

```
---
:backends:
 - yaml
 - eyaml
:hierarchy:
   - "%{::osfamily}/%{::environ}/%{::appname}"

:yaml:
  :datadir: 'C:\temp\var'
:eyaml:
  :datadir: 'C:\temp\var\eyaml'
  :key_id: '<key_id>'
  :aws_region: 'eu-west-1'
  :extension: 'yaml'
```

I'm using hiera-eyaml-kms-0.0.1 gem

even i have tried setting it in environment variable- AWS_REGION

Comment: That hiera config looks off, but we also need to see your manifest to help troubleshoot since the error being thrown is on a function call in there.

Comment: I'm just using some password secrets in erb to convert to PS1 at runtime         below is erb template im using - `keytool -export -keystore "E:\jboss\certs\OracleAdsKeyStore.jks" -alias ads<%= @environ %> -file "E:\java\jdk8\32bit\jre\lib\security\ads<%= @environ %>.cer"  -storepass <%= @oracle_export %>` and below is refered hiera variable in manifest `$oracle_export = hiera('java_exportkey')`  @Matt Schuchard

Answer (score 0):

Change the following in your hiera.yaml

```
:eyaml:  
 :aws_region: 'eu-west-1' -> :kms_aws_region: 'eu-west-1'
```